# Defining relative path to an image using CSS: background-image url

Tags: html, css

Suppose i have a 'root' folder on my desktop called New_Website. I then have four sub folders. main_files, website_images, website_others, website_stylesheets.

If website_stylesheets contains stylesheet.css and website images contains randomimg.jpg, how do i get from stylesheet.css to randomimg.jpg using CSS - background-image: url(relative path); ?

Comment: `background-image: url('../website_images/randomimg.jpg');`

Comment: logic would think that. Although this doesn't seem to work

Comment: do you have any errors in your browser console?

Comment: GET file:///C:/Users/New%20User/Desktop/New_Website/website_stylesheets/randomimage.jpg net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Comment: it's looking for randomimage.jpg in website_stylesheets. No mention of "website_images". You have an error in your code somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me (I made the `New_Website` in the desktop with 3 folders inside and 1 file in each one):

`index.html` (inside the `main_files` folder)

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="C:\Users\...\Desktop\New_Website\website_stylesheets\stylesheet.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

`stylesheet.css` (inside `website_stylesheets` folder)

```
body {
  background-color: gray;
}
div {
  background-image: url('file:///C:/Users/.../Desktop/New_Website/website_images/randomimg.jpg');
  height: 70px;
  width: 83px;
}
```

`randomimg.jpg` (inside `website_images` folder)

[image]

(it's a white image)

Comment: how do absolute paths fair out when a website goes online? surely absolute paths wouldn't work?

Comment: @Dylan: Pretty sure this is nothing new. Most websites use url to their local images.

Comment: Is there any harm in putting the images in the folder that contains the stylesheet? It is probably bad practice but would it have any ill-effects?

Comment: @Dylan: None that I know of.